# ¿Cómo formatear fechas en Java, pudiendo recibir fechas en distintos formatos?

Tags: java, date

Quiero tener el siguiente formato de fecha al realizar un `System.out.println()`: `21/05/2018 13:11:12` (dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss), independientemente del formato con el que se reciba el String que creará la fecha.

Utilizo las clases

```
import java.util.Date;

import java.text.DateFormat;

java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

para darle formato correcto, y utilizo esta forma, con una fecha con un solo formato concreto (la idea es poder interpretar la fecha que recibe el codigo, independientemente del formato en el que entre):

```
SimpleDateFormat fec = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = fec.parse("2018-05-21T13:11:12");
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date));
```

Pero no me deja crear la fecha con cualquier formato

Comment: Enrique, el problema es que si, como dices, recibes la cadena de fecha en **diferentes formatos o con contenido distinto**, sería cuestión de determinar partiendo de la cadena recibida el formato específico que tiene la fecha y a partir de ahí crear entonces el objeto. Sobre todo si te interesa conservar la hora. Creo que sería bueno que edites la pregunta poniendo todos los formatos de fecha posible que recibirías, y que le pongas a la pregunta la etiqueta `regex`, de modo que alguien te pueda ayudar en base a expresiones regulares. Creo que sería el camino adecuado para resolver tu problema.

Comment: Buenas, el problema es que en mi aplicación no puedo saber exactamente con qué formatos va a llegar, y si defino ciertos formatos puede que entre otra fecha en la que el formato no tenga nada que ver, no tengo acceso a la base de datos para controlar como se almacenan esas fechas que recibo y no son fechas como tal en la base de datos, está fatal hecha y no puedo cambiar esa parte ...

Comment: Un claro ejemplo de [garbage in, gargabe out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No se puede.

Para empezar, "independientemente del formato que se entre" es definitivamente demasiado amplio. Incluso si nos limitamos a formatos más convencionales, es imposible decidir si "05/12/11" es "5 de diciembre de 2011" o "12 de mayo de 2011" o "11 de diciembre de 2005" o ... El conversor necesita información externa para saber qué significa cada dígito, que es por lo que tú le indicas cuál es el formato esperado.

Naturalmente, cuando el dato introducido no se corresponde con el formato esperado, la conversión falla, pues es lo más seguro.

Siempre puedes poner una lista de `SimpleDateFormat` con los distintos formatos y probarlos hasta que uno no falle. No lo recomiendo, porque hará conversiones que el usuario no esperará. Una vez introducirá "01/12/2018" y lo leerá en un formato, otra vez introducirá "01/13/2018" y lo leerá en otro.

Si lo que quieres es simplemente "que me pueda poner la fecha con o sin hora", entonces es más sencillo. En general recomendaría usar una expresión regular (mira la clase `Pattern`) para evaluar si la cadena incluye la hora o no, y según eso usa el `SimpleDateFormat` adecuado o añade una hora "por defecto" al final de la cadena.

Comment: Eso me temía, pero quería cerciorarme, el problema viene a nivel de la base de datos, en la cual yo no puedo hacer nada, no tengo acceso. Y las fechas dentro de la misma no son fechas como tal, sino cadenas, con lo cual la base de datos traga sin miedo, pero claro, Java es otro mundo :(

Comment: Siempre puedes leer los valores como cadenas y presentarlos tal cual, pero claro, los usuarios (y los responsables de la organización) deberían saber que no se puede confiar en el formato.

Comment: Ya, la idea era ver si se podía evitar justo eso, pero no va a ser posible. Muchas gracias, cierro la pregunta y te doy la buena. :)

Comment: Excelente respuesta. En estos casos, @enriquemanzanogil hay una sola solución: **normalizar los datos en la base de datos almacenándolos como columnas del tipo `DATETIME`... cueste lo que cueste**. La situación planteada en tu pregunta demuestra que la información ha llegado a un estado imposible de mantener y que es altamente propensa a generar datos erróneos y peligrosos. Imaginemos una BD de un hospital en la que hay que suministrar ciertos medicamentos cruciales en determinadas fechas y el sistema se confunde. Quizá no sea el caso, pero esas pueden ser algunas de las consecuencias...

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar varias instancias de `SimpleDateFormat`, unas para recibir fechas y otras para escribirlas:

```
SimpleDateFormat parser = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy'T'HH:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
Date date = parser.parse("2018-05-21T13:11:12");
System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
```